# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n) : PrimeNg Module federation

Tags: angular, typescript, components, primeng

Getting injection error for service class when used inside a custom dialog service component

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[MyService -> MyService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MyService!

Below provider already mentioned in the module class

```
@NgModule({
     providers: [
        MyService
      ]
}
```

**ConfigurationComponent.ts**

Calling below method to show dialog from another component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-configuration',
  templateUrl: './configuration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./configuration.component.scss'],
  providers :[DialogService]
})

export class ConfigurationComponent{

    constructor(private dialogService: DialogService)

    showTestDialog(){
       this.dialogService.open(DialogTestComponent, {
        header: 'Select a Product',
          showHeader: false,
          width: '50%',
          contentStyle: { overflow: 'auto' },
          baseZIndex: 10000,
          maximizable: false,
          closable: false
        });
      }
}
```

**DialogTestComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-test',
  templateUrl: './dialog-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-test.component.scss'],
})
export class DialogTestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private myService: MyService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData()
  }
  getData(){
    this.myService.getListData()
    .subscribe({
      next: (data: ListResponse) => {
      },
      error: (error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  }
}
```